# Moment generating function, possible values and probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I have two independent random variables X and Y such that the moment generating functions are respectively $G_X(t)= 1/3 + (2t)/3$ and $G_Y(t)= 1/4 + t/2 + t^2/4$.

If we consider $Z = X+Y$ . What would be the possible values of Z? and $P(Z=1)$?

I tried to find the moment generating function of Z with the product of $G_X(t)$ and $G_Y(t)$,
but I didn't get the possible values nor P(Z=1).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your functions are denoted by $G$ and they have no exponentials in them, you are not looking at moment generating functions but [probability generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function), and so $X$ and $Y$ can be read off from the coefficients:
$$p_X(x)=\begin{cases}1/3&x=0\\2/3&x=1\end{cases}$$
$$p_Y(x)=\begin{cases}1/4&x=0\\1/2&x=1\\1/4&x=2\end{cases}$$
Thus the possible values of $Z$ are $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $P(Z=1)=\frac13\frac12+\frac23\frac14=\frac13$.